# Is there a way to switch to another theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Is there a method that exists that will let me switch the theme?

**Update:**
It looks like switch_theme is the [method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) and there is also an [event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme) of the same name. It says that it accepts an argument of stylesheet and for backwards compatibility it accepts, $themename and $stylesheet. I guess I don't understand, why is someone changing the stylesheet and no longer changing the theme?

Comment: [`switch_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)?

Comment: Assuming you mean programmatically?

Comment: @jdm2112 yes. i believe that switch_theme is an event that happens when someone switches a different theme. Oh, that's different. I was looking at the action of the same name, https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme. Milo I believe that's what I'm looking for. but why is it passed the stylesheet and not the theme name?

Comment: Although you have already accepted an answer, I have a question. Do you want to permanently switch to another theme for everyone or to switch to another theme on the fly but not permanently and only for current user?

Comment: I have a network site and I want the current user to be able to switch the theme permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch_theme()` is the function you need but this...

> why is someone changing the stylesheet and no longer changing the
>   theme?

... indicates a misunderstanding. You provide the `$stylesheet` as an argument but you are switching the theme as a whole not just the stylesheet. And, for reasons unknown, `$stylesheet` isn't the stylesheet. It is:

> `$stylesheet` is the name of your folder slug. It's the same value that
>   you'd use for a child theme, something like `twentythirteen`.
>
> > https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme

Comment: So it sounds like the parameter name is a bit misleading? I'm sure there's probably some history to it or reason.

Comment: I don't know what the reasons is, but yes, it is quite misleading.

Comment: I'm curious, which action is the more appropiate to run `switch_theme()`. I think on `init` but maybe `setup_theme`?

Comment: @cybmeta sorry. I didn't see this comment. I'm not sure. I'm going to try to run it when a new blog is created. I'll try and find the event.

Comment: I'm making a call at the `add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'wpse_set_defaults' );`. If it's not obvious, I'm running a network site. You will want to find a different action if you are not running the same. Right now, I'm adding an event listener in a plugin page for some reason. I think it should probably be in theme/functions...